# Issue in using the data that is being fetched from Excel sheet

Tags: java, selenium

I've the following code where fetching of data from excel sheet is done and then this data is added to list as below:

```
  List<HashMap<String,String>> mydata = new ArrayList<>();
  try 
  {
     FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(filepath);
     XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
     XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
     Row HeaderRow = sheet.getRow(0);
     for(int i=1;i<sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();i++)
     {
        Row currentRow = sheet.getRow(i);
        HashMap<String,String> currentHash = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(int j=0;j<currentRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();j++)
        {
           Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(j);
           switch (currentCell.getCellType())
           {
           case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:        
           currentHash.put(HeaderRow.getCell(j).getStringCellValue(), currentCell.getStringCellValue());
              break;                                  
           }
        }
        mydata.add(currentHash);
```

I've another class where we are making use Properties class and setting the property :

```
 public List<HashMap<String,String>> datamap;
 public static Properties prop;
public void read_Data_FromExcel(String arg1) throws Throwable {
     datamap = DataHelper.data("C:/FINALORDER/ORDERING_Tools/ordering-tools/src/test/resources/Test451.xlsx","Sheet1");
        prop=new Properties();
          int index = Integer.parseInt(arg1)-2;
          FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("C:\\FINALORDER\\ORDERING_Tools\\ordering-tools\\src\\test\\resources\\Test451.xlsx");
             XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
             XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
             Row HeaderRow = sheet.getRow(0);
             for(int i=0;i<HeaderRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();i++) {
            prop.setProperty(HeaderRow.getCell(i).toString(), datamap.get(index).get(HeaderRow.getCell(i).toString()));
```

Using the above code i m fetching the data from excel and then inputting that data into the fields present in the screen like below:

```
  try {
    String remark=ExcelSteps.prop.getProperty("Remark");
    mosdpOrderSummaryEditPage.tbx_remarks.type(remark);
    }catch(Exception e) {
    }
```

The issue is if there are many fields like remark,name,address,id then i have to fetch them one by one using the above code as for remark which is sort of redundant work and increasing code unnecessarily , is there a way by which i can reduce the code or make any generic method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate column and get those through

```
ExcelSteps.prop.getProperty("Here you should pass the column data");
```

By this code will automatically get remark,name,address,id field names dynamically.
:)

Comment: i didnt get what you mean